# Is protocol buffer SerializeToString stable across architectures?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is the protocol buffer (syntax 3) `SerializeToString` method guaranteed to give the same output on different architectures for the same data file that is read in and then `SerializeToString` called?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, protobuf is architecture-independent.

(It would not be a very good serialization format if it weren't.)